# Numerical evidence that $\pi$ is not normal in base two

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

Confusion is possible, but we got numerical evidence against
popular belief about the normality of $\pi$ in base two.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number)

> a real number is said to be **simply normal** in an integer base b if its infinite sequence of digits is distributed uniformly in the sense that each of the b digit values has the same natural density 1/b. A number is said to be **normal** in base b if, for every positive integer n, all possible strings n digits long have density b^-n.

Working with precision ten thousands binary digits and n=2,
the counts of the strings in $\pi$ are:
$(11: 1661, 10:  2505,  01:  2505, 00:  1659)$

$10$ occurs about 1.5 times more than $11$.

$\pi$ appears to be simply normal in base four.

The same discrepancy happens for $\sqrt{2}$, $\log{3}$ and
large random integers.

Is $\pi$ not normal in base two and $n=2$?

Computations were done with sagemath and pari/gp.

**Added** The shorter of the two programs, are there obvious bugs in it?

```
 sage: pre=10^4
 sage: gp.default('realprecision',pre)
 0
 sage: sp=gp.binary(gp.Pi())
 sage: sp2=eval(str(sp[2]));sp3="".join(str(_) for _ in sp2)
 sage: sp3.count('11'),sp3.count('10'),sp3.count('01'),sp3.count('00')
 (5586, 8289, 8290, 5529)
```

Comment: How could this happen for random integers? Also, shouldn't your numbers add up to 10000?

Comment: They should still add up to 10000 (give or take a few): the first 10000 bits contain 9999 consecutive bit pairs

Comment: You are probably counting substrings without overlaps?

Comment: The numbers I get are $2510,2505,2505,2480$ (give or take 1 on each). Could you perhaps share the code you have used?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე This has to be it - if you every time you see $11$ you delete it and move on to the next one, you're essentially counting occurrences of $011$, $01111$, $0111111, \dots$, which gives $1/2^3 + 1/2^5 + 1/2^7 + \dots = 1/6$.

Comment: @Wojowu I edited with the program, are there bugs in my program?

Comment: @WillSawin I edited with the program, are there bugs in my program?

Comment: From the data, we can tell with high confidence, without looking in the spec, that count does not allow overlaps.

Comment: e.g. see line 230 of https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h

Comment: For example, `"00000000".count('00')` gives 4

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Many thanks :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the comment strongly suggests the numerical data is just wrong.

Comment: A place to test sage code: [https://sagecell.sagemath.org/](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)

Comment: I also just want to point out that when I said the numbers should add up to 10000, I obviously meant plus or minus 1. (or even plus or minus 2 depending on how you count the digits before the "decimal" point) so the 110 is not a counterexample.

Comment: @WillSawin Many thanks for the debugging :) I wrote a lot of wrong stuff trying to "rationalize" the bug...

Answer (score 6):

This is more of a comment. I wanted to share the code I have used to provide values in my comment above.

```
s00 = 0
s01 = 0
s10 = 0
s11 = 0
a = 0
b = 0
P = pi
for i in range(10000):
    a = b
    b = floor(P)%2
    P = 2*P
    if a==0 and b==0:
        s00 += 1
    if a==0 and b==1:
        s01 += 1
    if a==1 and b==0:
        s10 += 1
    if a==1 and b==1:
        s11 += 1
print s00,s01,s10,s11
```

This code returns `2510 2505 2505 2480`. I'm afraid I cannot comment on what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Thanks, your code seems reasonable, will check

Comment: The bug in my code was found, I incorrectly didn't count overlaps.